# Is it possible to create our own threads with out using operating system threads?

Tags: database, multithreading, operating-system, rdbms

I was reading an article about how database management works. in that article author has mentioned that some of the modern databases use their own threads instead of operating system threads. 
Is it true? If yes how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to fully replace OS threads, but a database can use other 'thread-like' facilities, like [Fibers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682661(v=vs.85).aspx) or asynchronous calls.

For example, the Microsoft SQL Server has a core component called SQL Server Operating System *(SQLOS)*. SQLOS is responsible for low-level operations of the database like scheduling or resource-management.

SQLOS advances the core operating system thread management in order to minimize the expensive context changes and the costly user-kernel mode switching. It also uses cooperative scheduling instead of the preemptive Windows scheduler.

A database operation is executed by one of the *worker* threads, which are managed by one of the *schedulers*.

Regardless, at the very low-level the SQLOS uses Windows threads just like any other application, what differs is the thread management and scheduling.

For more information on custom thread scheduling, you can check Windows's User-mode scheduling [(UMS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd627187(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation.